# Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(penguins)+
   geom_point(mapping=aes(x=flipper_length_mm,y=body_mass_g,shape=year))
```

this is the code using `palmerpenguins` dataset and why it is not working?
can someone help me out

> Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Comment: Hi, you can check the docs for the aesthetics that you are using, .e.g: 
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html

In your case, year is a continuous variable, whereas "shape" would rather like to get categorical values. You can imagine that it is not really useful to have a continuous transformations of shapes into each other, or something like that. You want distinct, categorical shapes. To do that, you can turn the years into factors! Try this: 


ggplot(penguins)+  
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=flipper_length_mm,y=body_mass_g,shape=as.factor(year)))

Comment: Year is a numeric variable so you have to convert  it to a character or a factor.